# flip using css3 and jquery

Tags: jquery, css, animation

Im trying to create a flip page using jquery and css3. I can do it if I put my 2 pages in 1 container and then rotates the entire container, but id like to rotate my pages only. This is my code:

css:

```
#pagecontainer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.page {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;    
}
.back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip.out {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.0s linear;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transition: all 1.0s linear;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transition: all 1.0s linear;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: all 1.0s linear;
 }

.flip.in {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.0s linear;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transition: all 1.0s linear;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transition: all 1.0s linear;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: all 1.0s linear;
 }
```

I then add these classes to my pages within the pagecontainer:

```
container.append(nextPage);
nextPage.attr("class", "page back");
currentPage.one('webkitTransitionEnd', function(e) {
    currentPage.remove();
});
nextPage.attr("class", "page back flip in");
container[0].offsetWidth;
currentPage.attr("class", "page flip out");
```

But only the front is flipping? what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
Solved it. I needed to change the order in my script, to:

```
currentPage.attr("class", "page flip out"); <-- Start with this 
container[0].offsetWidth;
nextPage.attr("class", "page back flip in"); <-- Finish with this
```

Comment: show you code http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this plugin and his source code http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/09/03/bookblock-a-content-flip-plugin/
And remember that even IE10 doesnt support preserve-3d